# Why am I getting no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

For some reason my connection to heroku started failing. I am guessing Heorku made some sort of change as all 3 of my computers stopped working within the same week.

If I run "`ssh -vT git@heroku.com`"

I get

```
    [brian@stat-vm ~]$ ssh -vT git@heroku.com
    OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
    debug1: Reading configuration data /home/brian/.ssh/config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/brian/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version endosome
    debug1: no match: endosome
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 server hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256
```

Can anyone suggest a fix or tell me what is going on?

Comment: The version of ssh that you're using is pretty old. You should start by upgrading it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](https://blog.tinned-software.net/debug-ssh-connection-issue-in-key-exchange/), this means the client and server could not setup a session as they could not agree on a MAC (message authentication code) algorithm.

The first thing to test is to make sure you have the latest Git installed, as well as the [latest openssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html).

Comment: I am on Centos 6.4 and when I try to update OpenSSH it says I am up to date. sudo yum install openssh-server Package openssh-server-5.3p1-123.el6_9.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: @jdog openssl is still old though. Any way to upgrade it?